# Issue with installing Git via Homebrew on Mac

Tags: git, homebrew

I'm trying to set up Git for the first time so that I can import my project from VS Code. It's been pretty frustrating trying to figure it out on my own.

I tried to install Git by following a YouTube video, but my terminal gave me this message:

```
==> You are using macOS 10.13.
==> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
This installation may not succeed.
After installation, you will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving any
issues you experience while you are running this old version.

==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
```

I don't know if I should proceed, as I don't want to come across any major issues when trying to share my projects. Should I, or is there something else that I need to do?

I copied/pasted this into my terminal from Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Yes, this is fine. One of the things homebrew does is provide pre-built binaries for most (all?) of its formulas. When using an older version of macOS, it just means that you'll download the source and compile the formula on your machine (taking longer). This is more error prone, hence their disclaimer. But perfectly fine to use and try.

Comment: You may want to consider MacPorts. See the accepted answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280203/install-old-version-of-homebrew-on-snow-leopard